# Разрешение на использование геолокации

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iphone

Всем привет! У меня при запуске приложения сразу же спрашивается разрешение на использовании геолокации, как я могу отключить это и вызывать этот алерт перед тем местом где я действительно собираюсь использовать гео?

Answer (score 3):

Добавляем следующие в **.plist* файл ключ `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` или `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`, в зависимости от того, как будет приложение работать с геолокацией (только, когда приложение используется или всегда).

Импортируем `CoreLocation` для работы с `CLLocationManager`:

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
```

Добавляем свойство в наш контроллер:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

И где нужно, например, в методе `viewDidLoad` инициализируем и запрашиваем одно из разрешений на использование геолокации:

```
self.locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];

[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
//[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
```

Больше информации:

http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/